# Объединение данных из разных столбцов в строку

Tags: sql

Кто может подсказать, как объединить данные из разных столбцов в одну строку?

Есть представление, созданное из запроса:

```
SELECT cardID, dateTo, dateFrom FROM bookTurover GROUP BY cardID, dateTo, dateFrom;
```

Имеет вид:

```
cardID | dateTo     | dateFrom
111  __| 2018-05-03 | null
111  __| null_______| 2018-07-02
222  __| 2019-01-20 | null
222  __| null_______| 2019-02-15
```

Надо сделать, чтобы можно было считать разницу между dateFrom и dateTo для каждого cardID, то есть таблица (представление) должна иметь такой вид:

```
cardID | dateTo     | dateFrom
111 ___| 2018-05-03 | 2018-07-02
222 ___| 2019-01-20 | 2019-02-15
```

Comment: Есть вопросы по такой конструкции. Если у вас для одной cardID может быть только одна dateTo и одна dateFrom, то нужно хранить их в одной строке, с уникальным cardID, и тогда вывод будет такой, как вам нужен. А если для одной карты может быть более одной dateTo или dateFrom, то совсем не понятно, как их объединять.

Comment: Какую именно СУБД используете?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо ответившим, но проблема уже решена через создание представлений)

```
go
create view temp as
select  cardID, inventoryNumber, dateTo, dateFrom from bookTurnover group by 
cardID, inventoryNumber, dateTo, dateFrom;
go
create view toto as
select cardID, inventoryNumber, dateTo from temp where dateTo is not null 
go 
create view fro as 
select cardID, dateFrom from temp where dateFrom is not null
go
create view mainForProc as
select toto.cardID as читатель, toto.inventoryNumber as книга,toto.dateTo as выдано,      
fro.dateFrom as сдано from toto full outer join fro on toto.cardID = fro.cardID 
go
```

P.S. СУБД - MS SQL Server. К вопросу о способе хранения: выбран именно такой, так как нужно учитывать какой сотрудник проводит сдачу, а какой выдачу, поэтому и даты так раскиданы.

результат на рисунке[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Комментирующий прав, очень странное хранение данных, но решить этот вопрос можно очень многими способами, здесь лишь 3 из них:

```
set dateformat ymd
declare @table table (cardID int,dateTo datetime,dateFrom datetime)
insert into @table
select
111 cardID, '2018-05-03' dateTo, null dateFrom
union all
select 111 cardID, null dateTo, '2018-07-02' dateFrom
union all
select 222 cardID, '2019-01-20' dateTo, null dateFrom
union all
select 222 cardID, null dateTo, '2019-02-15' dateFrom

--В лоб джойн самой к себе
select  isnull(t1.cardID,t2.cardID) cardID,
        t1.dateFrom,
        t2.dateTo 
from @table t1
left join @table t2  on t2.cardID=t1.cardID and t2.dateTo is not null
where t1.dateFrom is not null

--Возможно лиф лаг использовать
select cardID, dateTo, dateFrom from
(
    select cardID, 
        dateTo, 
        LEAD(dateFrom) OVER (partition by cardID order by dateFrom) dateFrom,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by CardID order by dateTo desc) Rn 
    FROM @table
) x
where x.Rn=1

--MAX min
select cardID, dateTo, dateFrom from (
select cardID,
       Max(dateTo) over (partition by CardID) dateTo,
       Max(dateFrom) over (partition by CardID) dateFrom,
       ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CardID order by dateTo) Rn
FROM @table GROUP BY cardID, dateTo, dateFrom
) x
where Rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Если используемая вами СУБД имеет функции агрегации строк, то с её помощью код получается простейшим:

```
select cardID, string_agg(dateTo, ''), string_agg(dateFrom, '')
from table
group by cardID
```

Этот пример для Sql Server 2017. Функция [STRING_AGG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

В MySQL аналогичная функция называется GROUP_CONCAT().